# POI for evaluate excel sheet formula

Tags: excel, grails

I am trying to evaluate excel sheet formula using below code

```
    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workBook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator()
        for(Row row : sheet){
         for(Cell cell : row) {
            if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                switch (evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell)) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    print "Boolean "
                    break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    print "Numeric  "
                    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                        print cell.getDateCellValue()
                    } else {
                        print cell.getNumericCellValue()
                    }
                    break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    print "String "
                    break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                    break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                    break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                        print "Formula : " + cell.getCellFormula()
                    break;

                }
            }

         }
    }
```

but I am getting this below error any suggestion!!

Array index out of range: -3. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -3
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaCellCacheEntrySet.addInternal(FormulaCellCacheEntrySet.java:83)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaCellCacheEntrySet.add(FormulaCellCacheEntrySet.java:72)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CellCacheEntry.addConsumingCell(CellCacheEntry.java:85)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaCellCacheEntry.changeConsumingCells(FormulaCellCacheEntry.java:80)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaCellCacheEntry.setSensitiveInputCells(FormulaCellCacheEntry.java:60)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaCellCacheEntry.updateFormulaResult(FormulaCellCacheEntry.java:109)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CellEvaluationFrame.updateFormulaResult(CellEvaluationFrame.java:75)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.EvaluationTracker.updateCacheResult(EvaluationTracker.java:94)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:286)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:221)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:257)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:150)
    at img.managedvolatility.ReportController$_generateReport_closure6.doCall(ReportController.groovy:121)
    at img.managedvolatility.ReportController.generateReport(ReportController.groovy:68)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:148)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:94)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1021)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1381)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.xs.sessionmanager.HttpSessionFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionFilter.java:687)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1021)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4983)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31.handleRequest(WebApp31.java:528)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:315)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:280)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:359)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1777)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:809)

Comment: show the code on ReportController.groovy:68

Comment: I resolved this issue.. Thanks